# How to display multiple markers with different icons in Google Maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am parsing a XML file for the data to place the markers. I currently have the locations plotted using a single image. What I am trying to do is set a different color marker based on a vaule from the XML file. Here is an example of the XML file.

```
    <fatalities>
<fatalities yrnum="1" date="2013-01-30" dt="Jan. 30, 2013" time="10:12:00" tz="CST" location="BARTOW" st="GA" deaths="1" intor="1" insvr="0" nrsvr="0" nowatch="0" watch="WT0019" ef="3" h="0" m="1" o="0" p="0" v="0" unk="0" slat="34.342" slon="-84.9527" elat="34.5981" elon="-84.7313"/>
<fatalities yrnum="2" date="2013-02-21" dt="Feb. 21, 2013" time="13:10:00" tz="CST" location="SABINE" st="TX" deaths="1" intor="0" insvr="0" nrsvr="0" nowatch="1" watch="NONE" ef="1" h="0" m="1" o="0" p="0" v="0" unk="0" slat="31.32" slon="-93.97" elat="31.32" elon="-93.98"/>
<fatalities yrnum="3" date="2013-04-11" dt="Apr. 11, 2013" time="10:38:00" tz="CST" location="KEMPER" st="MS" deaths="1" intor="0" insvr="0" nrsvr="0" nowatch="1" watch="NONE" ef="3" h="0" m="0" o="0" p="1" v="0" unk="0" slat="32.63" slon="-88.88" elat="33.42" elon="-88.20"/>
<summary STATE="GA" FATALITIES="1"/>
<summary STATE="MS" FATALITIES="1"/>
<summary STATE="TX" FATALITIES="1"/>
<csummary H="0" M="2" O="0" P="1" V="0" UNK="0"/>
<total TOTAL="3"/>
</fatalities>
```

The value is ef in the XML file to determine which maker to place at the location. I haven't used Google Maps in years but I have been re-learning it the past couple of weeks and I have been going through many examples and search the web for answers and I really haven't found anything.

Here is a link to the test page I have set up.The markers I need to use are at the bottom. I can plot the locations using a single marker but once I try to use different markers based off the ef value from the XML I get nothing. So bascially I need to plot all markers by location. Depending on the ef value in the XML it needs to be a certain color marker.

http://www.mesquiteweather.net/xml/googlemapkt.html

Here is the code I have for this.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  var infowindow;
  var map;

// start here

    var summary_html = "";
    var csummary_html = "";
    var total_html = "";
    var gmarkers = [];
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var thisurl = '2013.xml';


  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.775833, -96.796667);
    var myOptions = {
      panControl: false,
      zoom: 4,
          mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
      center: myLatlng,     
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

   function MyLogoControl(controlDiv) {
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';
    var logo = document.createElement('IMG');
    logo.src = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net/images/watermark_MW_GMap.png';
    logo.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlDiv.appendChild(logo);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(logo, 'click', function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.mesquiteweather.net'; 
    });
  }

   var logoControlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
   var logoControl = new MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv);
   logoControlDiv.index = 0; // used for ordering
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);


    downloadUrl(thisurl, function(data) {
      var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("fatalities");
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var yrnum = markers[i].getAttribute("yrnum");
          var dt = markers[i].getAttribute("dt");
          var tm = markers[i].getAttribute("time");
          var ef = markers[i].getAttribute("ef");
          var st = markers[i].getAttribute("st");
          var loc = markers[i].getAttribute("location");
          var watch = markers[i].getAttribute("watch");
          var dead = markers[i].getAttribute("deaths");
          var h = markers[i].getAttribute("h");
          var m = markers[i].getAttribute("m");
          var o = markers[i].getAttribute("o");
          var v = markers[i].getAttribute("v");
          var p = markers[i].getAttribute("p");
          var unk = markers[i].getAttribute("unk");

          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("slat")),
                                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("slon")));
          var epoint = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("elat")),
                                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("elon")));

          var marker = createMarker(point, yrnum, dt, ef, tm, dead, h, m, o, v, p, unk, loc, st, watch);
          marker.setMap(map);

          var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: [point, epoint], 
              strokeColor: lineColor[ef],
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2
              });

          polyline.setMap(map);
       }
     });
      }

 var customIcons = {
"-1":                   "/images/icons/mm_1_white.png",
"0":                    "/images/icons/mm_20_white.png",
"1":                    "/images/icons/mm_20_orange.png",
"2":                    "/images/icons/mm_20_green.png",
"3":                    "/images/icons/mm_20_blue.png",
"4":                    "/images/icons/mm_20_red.png",
"5":                    "/images/icons/mm_20_black.png"

};

var lineColor = {
"-1":                   "#FFFFFF",
"0":                    "#FFFFFF",
"1":                    "#FFA500",
"2":                    "#008000",
"3":                    "#0000FF",
"4":                    "#FF0000",
"5":                    "#000000"

};

  function createMarker(point, yrnum, dt, ef, tm, dead, h, m, o, v, p, unk, loc, st, watch) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, icon: customIcons[ef]});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: location});
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;

  }

</script>
```

Any help or suggestions would be great!

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, this is not really a problem but is improper: change var logoControl = new MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv); to var logoControl = MyLogoControl(logoControlDiv); as there is no need for the 'new' keyword there as MyLogoControl does not return a new object.
Now, below there (on the test page you have linked to here) you have to remove the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

as you already have map defined earlier using myOptions and mapOptions is not defined.
Then, the first line within your downloadUrl function, remove this:

```
var xml = GXml.parse(data);
```

as it is not needed. Those are the main issues there which I noted. I should also note that your createXmlHttpRequest() function is improper as it first checks for the existence of window.ActiveXObject and that should be avoided as XMLHttpRequest() is now more prevalent and standard and should be used wherever available including in IE7+. So, I recommend changing your createXmlHttpRequest() function to the following:

```
function createXmlHttpRequest() {
    var xhr = null;
    try{//Mozilla, Safari, IE 7+...
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
            xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } catch(e) {// IE 6, use only Msxml2.XMLHTTP.(6 or 3).0,
         //see: http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx
        try{
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
        }catch(e){
            try{
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
            }catch(e){}
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

Then, one other thing I note is that this looks incorrect:
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: location});
I believe instead of {content: location} you want {content: loc}

Comment: Thank you for your help and response. I got that var logoControl example from a post on here. I do see what you mean and it makes sense and will keep that in mind.

The var map I probably left by mistake and overlooked it. So that is removed. 

As soon as I removed the var xml = GXml.parse(data); it started working perfectly. I didn't think that looked correct. Should have known it was something simple but I was trying different things. 

As far as the function XMLHttpRequest() where exactly do I use that?

for the info window it should be location right as that's the value from the XML?